# Finite subadditivity follows from finite additivity and the monotonicity property

Tags: measure-theory

Following along with Terence Tao's notes on Measure theory, so far

He defines elementary sets as a union of a finte number of boxes in $\mathbb{R^d}$

We have shown that if $E,F$ are elementary sets then their union, intersection, set theoretical difference and symmetric difference are also elementary sets.

Next it is stated that measures on elementary sets follow the finite additivity property that if $E_1, \ldots, E_k$ are disjoint elementary sets that $m(E_1 \cup \ldots \cup E_k) = m(E_1) + \ldots + m(E_k)$. It is also stated that if $E \subset F$ are elementary sets then $m(E) \leq m(F)$.

Now he states that the finite sub-additivity property must follow that $m(E \cup F) \leq m(E)+m(F)$ for any elementary sets $E,F$ (the monotonicity property).

Here is where I am stuck.

I write $E \cup F = (E\backslash F) \cup (F \backslash E) \cup (E \cap F)$,
and I get that $m(E\backslash F) \cup (F \backslash E) \cup (E \cap F)) = m(E\backslash F) + (F\backslash E) + m(E \cap F) $
$\leq m(E) + m(F) + m(E \cap F)$

since $(E \backslash F \subset E)$ and $(F \backslash E \subset F)$. This is not quite the desired result, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things a bit complicated. $\mu (E \cup F)=\mu (E \cup (F \setminus E)) =\mu (E)+\mu (F \setminus E)\leq \mu (E)+\mu (F)$.